# Boost Graph: What happens when calling remove_vertex on vertex with degree > 0

Tags: c++, boost-graph

From the boost graph manual for the function `remove_vertex`

> It is assumed that there are no edges to or from vertex u when it is removed. One way to make sure of this is to invoke clear_vertex() beforehand.

What happens if you do call `remove_vertex()` on a vertex that is connected to other vertices? Does it lead to undefined behavior?

From the quote in the manual it would seem that something **bad** will happen. If so why does it not throw an exception when called in this way?

Comment: Yes, something bad happened :-) Thanks for the pointer to `clear_vertex()` which helped to resolve the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apart from some algorithms and utilities, the Boost Graph Library in general does not throw exceptions, especially when accessing or modifying the structure of a graph. I guess this decision has been made due to performance reasons.

I'd compare this API model to STL. In STL violating a pre-condition leads to undefined behavior rather than to throwing an exception.